# How to include another HTML file in the HTML file in Vite and display images etc. on the dev server and in the preview after build. (Vanilla JS)

Tags: vite

Currently when I use a plugin called vite-plugin-ssinc to start a development server with Vite, I can include HTML files and develop comfortably.
However, when I build and preview the HTML in the included parts, the paths for images, etc. specify the img folder in the src folder instead of the file name with the hash value in dist/assets.
I tried using vite-plugin-handlebars and the result was the same.

Please tell me how to include HTML so that when the development server starts, HTML is included, images and other assets can be displayed, and furthermore, when built and previewed, the dist folder is specified in the path of the image assets in the included HTML.  I also don't use React or Vue.

directory

```
- src
  - index.html
  - img
    - index.jpeg
    - footer.jpeg
  - include
    - footer.html
- dist
```

Before Build (Using vite-plugin-handlebars.)

```
<body>

  <img src="/img/index.jpeg" alt="" />

  {{> footer}}

</body>
```

After Build

```
<body>

  <img src="/assets/index-Czl4CInw.jpeg" alt="" />

<footer>
  <img src="../img/footer.jpeg" alt="" />  //I want this to refer to an image with a hash value in the dist/assets folder instead of the src folder.
<footer>

</body>
```